# Magento1 PDF issue after extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, tax, pdf, partial-invoice

I am using an extension for PDF, but the extension is giving the wrong value for tax when I partially create Invoice or Creditmemo, As I checked the Extension is using "Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default" Model object, Here is the code segment:

```
//function1:
/*
 * Get Totals information.
*/
$totals = $this->_getTotalsList($creditmemo); //This function has issue
$totalArr = array();
foreach ($totals as $total) {
    $total->setOrder($order)
    ->setSource($creditmemo);
    if ($total->canDisplay()) {
        $area = $total->getSourceField()=='grand_total'?'footer':'body';
        foreach ($total->getTotalsForDisplay() as $totalData) {
            $totalArr[$area][] = new Varien_Object(array('label'=>$totalData['label'], 'value'=>$totalData['amount']));
        }
    }
}
======================================================

//function2:
protected function _getTotalsList($source)
{
        $totals = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/pdf/totals')->asArray();
        usort($totals, array($this, '_sortTotalsList'));
        $totalModels = array();
        foreach ($totals as $index => $totalInfo) {
            if (!empty($totalInfo['model'])) {
                $totalModel = Mage::getModel($totalInfo['model']);
        //After this instance It will take order's tax amount instead of invoice/credit memo
                if ($totalModel instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default) {
                    $totalInfo['model'] = $totalModel;
                } else {
                    Mage::throwException(
                        Mage::helper('sales')->__('PDF total model should extend Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default')
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $totalModel = Mage::getModel($this->_defaultTotalModel);
            }
            $totalModel->setData($totalInfo);
            $totalModels[] = $totalModel;
        }
        return $totalModels;
    }
```

Suggest how can I fix it.

Comment: In $totalModel, what it returning ? Use the log file and debug the tax

Comment: I am using "EasyInvoicePdf" extension, Is anybody using this?